# Scatterplot bounded by parabola

Tags: regression, python, data-visualization, logarithm

I have frequency data for several variables. Each type can take on one of two variants:

```
variable    freq1    freq2
A           6        6564
B           125      2227
C           1        5
(etc.)
```

I want to show that overall type frequency (of both variants) is negatively correlated with freq2: The higher the frequency of the variable overall, the more likely it is that it has the second variant.

I did this by regressing the log total frequency (freq1+freq2) versus the log of (freq2/freq1). My plot looks like this.

[image: correlation]

The plot seems to be bounded by $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ or some variation thereof. have a feeling that a linear regression is not well suited to show what I want to show.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a model that would demonstrate the trend I detect in my data, and for the visualization of the trend? I'm using Python matplotlib/seaborn.

Comment: Can you say more about your data? What are these? Are the `A, B, C, ...` the study units (some analog of patients)? What are the two types? Etc.

Comment: gung they are frequency counts of morphological variants for words. So for example xaaak occurs 12 times, and xaaam occurs 129 times. Jliiik occurs 110 times, and jliiim occurs 2,574 times, etc.

Comment: I've never heard of "xaaak", eg, is that some other language? So, are each of `A, B, C`, etc, a different morpheme? Are the 2 types morphemes ending in "k" vs ending in "m"? This is all a bit Greek to me...

Comment: Hi gung, no, those are not the actual words, and yes, freq1 is the number of times the type ends in k vs. freq2 the number of times it ends in m. I don't really need help with the language part of the project, though.

Comment: Presumably not, but we typically need to know more about the data, what they mean, etc., to determine what is going on.